# how to turn $ \large \int \sqrt {\frac{x}{x+1}} dx$ into a rational fraction?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

how to turn $ \large  \int \sqrt {\frac{x}{x+1}} dx$ into a rational fraction? is this even possible?

I mean turning $\sqrt {\frac{x}{x+1}}$ into such a fraction...

Comment: Hint: use trigonometric substitution to rewrite it as a function of another variable.

Comment: I note that while five people have upvoted my answer, I am the only person to have upvoted the question so far. If you find a response to question useful enough to merit upvoting, consider upvoting the question as well! ;)

Comment: @DavidH Low quality question => downvoted

Comment: @Fundamental have you also downvoted my other posts? cool for you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** The obvious substitution is $\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}=u$. Solving for $x$,

$$\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}=u\\
\frac{x}{x+1}=u^2\\
x=u^2(x+1)=u^2x+u^2\\
(1-u^2)x=u^2\\
x=\frac{u^2}{1-u^2}.$$

Taking differentials of both sides,

$$\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2u}{(1-u^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u.$$

Now, the integral becomes:

$$\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int u\cdot \frac{2u}{(1-u^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=2\int\frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u,\\
\end{align}$$

which is of course a rational integral.

Comment: I would go with the sub $u^2=\dfrac{x}{x+1}$ to get rid of that root also.

Comment: that's the conversion...

Answer (score 0):

### Method-I

Let $t^2=x+1$, then:
$$I=\int\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}}{t}\cdot2t{\rm d}t=2\int\sqrt{t^2-1}{\rm d}t=t\sqrt{t^2-1}-\ln|t+\sqrt{t^2-1}|+c\\=x\sqrt{x+1}-\ln|x+\sqrt{1+x}|+c$$

---

### Method-II

Let:
$$x=\tan^2\theta\\I=\int\frac{\tan\theta\cdot2\tan\theta\sec^2\theta\rm d\theta}{\sec\theta}=2\int\tan^2\theta\sec\theta{\rm d}\theta=2\left(\int\sec^3\theta{\rm d}\theta-\int\sec\theta{\rm d}\theta\right)\\=\sec\theta\tan\theta+\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|-2\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+c=x\sqrt{1+x}-\ln|x+\sqrt{1+x}|+c$$

---

### **Notes:**

- $\displaystyle\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}{\rm d}x=\frac x2\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2}2\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|+c$
- $\displaystyle\int\sec^3x{\rm d}x=\frac12\sec x\tan x+\frac12\ln|\sec x+\tan x|+c$

Comment: This is not a transformation to a rational function